# How to update an array item in the Realtime Database from within Android

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

> How to access a child inside real time database array child?

```
String count = item_count.getText().toString();

firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
reference = firebaseDatabase.getReference()
 
reference.child("beverages").child(????)
.child("item_count").setValue(count);
```

> this is my code but I don't know what should I put in the question
> marks.

[image: !enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxUuz.png)

Comment: Did you already try `reference.child("beverages").child("3").setValue(count);`?

Comment: I don't want number 3 especially I want them all

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `item_count` by using `foreach` loop inside the `onDataChange` method.

1. Lets say this is your model class for your `Beverage`.

```
public class Beverage {
    private long item_count;
    private String item_img;
    private String item_name;

    public Beverage beverage(long itemCount){
       this.item_count = itemCount;
       //and do others also...
    }

    //Here your get set...
}
```

2. Here you get the data as `arrayList`

```
reference.child("beverages").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            ArrayList<Beverage> beveragesList = new ArrayList<Beverage>();
            //Get children
            for (DataSnapshot snapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (snapShot.exists()) {
                    final Beverage beverage = snapShot.getValue(Beverage.class);
                    if (beverage != null){
                        //Her you got the data as array list
                        beverageList.add(beverage);
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.i("???","Db error: " + databaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't `ctrll + k` for that one

Comment: Fixed the code formatting (you can enclose it in three back-ticks too instead of ctrl+k).

Comment: but i want to update "item_count" not revert

Comment: @IsmaelHamzeh you want to update specific `item_count` for child 3 ?

Comment: No, i have recyclerView i want to update selected position

Comment: @IsmaelHamzeh please update your question include your recyclerview onClick

Answer (score 1):

You need to put child of beverages here like 0,1,2, or 3.

```
reference.child("beverages").child("3").child("item_count").setValue(count);
```